# Java Objects in Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

i would like to run the update function automatically for every object i create. What do I have to change in my code, unfortunately it doesn't work

How can I initialize an object in my ArrayList?

:(

Creating an Arraylist and initialize with name

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Zuhoerer Maria = new Zuhoerer("Maria");
        Zuhoerer Sepp = new Zuhoerer("Sepp");
        Zeitansager.sagAn();
    }
}

class Zuhoerer {
    private String name;
    private String Ansager;

    Zuhoerer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private void setAnsager(String datumstring) {
        Ansager = datumstring;
    }

    void update() {
        setAnsager(Zeitansager.getZeit());
        Zeitansager.schreibeEin(name);
        System.out.println(name + " hat gerade die die Zeitansage gehört: 
    [Datum/Uhrzeit]: " + Ansager);
        Zeitansager.trageAus(name);
    }
}

class Zeitansager {
    private static String datumString;
    private static ArrayList<String> abonnenten;

    Zeitansager(String datumString) {
        Zeitansager.datumString = datumString;
        abonnenten = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    static void schreibeEin(String name) {
        abonnenten.add(name);
    }

    static void trageAus(String name) {
        abonnenten.remove(name);
    } 


    static void sagAn() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY' 'HH:mm:ss");
        String datum = sdf.format(new Date());
        datumString = datum;
        for (int i=1; i <= abonnenten.size(); i++) {
            abonnenten.update();
        }
    }
    static String getZeit() {
        return datumString;
    }
}
```

update function is not called

Answer (score 3):

1. Your `ArrayList` in `Zeitansager` have to be of type `Zuhoerer` rather than `String`.
2. Then in your loop in `sagAn()` you need to invoke:

```
            abonnenten.get(i).update();
```

instead of:

```
            abonnenten.update();
```

3. Finally your method `static void schreibeEin(String name)`, should actually take a `Zuhoerer` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

To run "update" function every time you create an object you must put a call to this function inside your constructor. Like this:

```
Zuhoerer(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    update();
}
```

What are you trying to do with your arraylist? Give me more details so I can try to help you.